# Data is being shared with the same component used multiple times

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following components:

```js
//wrapper component
<template>
    <div class="form-group form-group-text">
        <label v-if="label" :for="fieldId()">{{ label }}</label>
        <tiny-wrapper :key="pk"
            class="form-control builderEditor"
            :id="id"
            :name="fieldName()"
            v-model="form[field.key]"
            :init="editorSettings"
            :content="field.content"
        ></tiny-wrapper>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import BuilderHelper from './builder-helper'
    import TinyWrapper from '../tiny-wrapper'

    export default Vue.extend({
        props: [
            'pk',
            'title',
            'fieldKey',
            'field',
            'databaseName',
            'required',
            'disabled',
            'options',
            'label',
            'locale',
            'hidden',
        ],

        mixins: [BuilderHelper],

        components: {
            'tiny-wrapper': TinyWrapper,
        },

        computed: {
            editorSettings() {
                return {
                    // editor_selector: '.builderEditor',
                    selector: '#' + this.id,
                    menubar: '',
                    toolbar: 'bold italic | link',
                    height: 150,
                    contextmenu: 'bold italic | link',
                    forced_root_block: false,
                    invalid_elements: 'script',
                    statusbar: false,
                    resize: false,
                    browser_spellcheck: true,
                }
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```

and

```js
// child component
<template>
    <textarea :id="id" ref="editor" class="form-control" :class="classList" :value="content"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import 'tinymce/tinymce'

    export default Vue.extend({
        props: {
            init: {
                type: Object,
            },
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            classList: {
                type: String,
            },
            value: {
                type: String,
            }
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                content: '',
                tinyOptions: {},
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            // this.content = this.value

            this.tinyOptions = Object.assign(window.tinyMCESettings, {
                selector: '#' + this.id,
                init_instance_callback: this.initInstanceCallback,
            }, this.init)

            tinymce.init(this.tinyOptions)
        },

        methods: {
            initInstanceCallback(editor) {
                editor.setContent(this.value)

                editor.on('change', e => {
                    this.update(editor)
                })

                editor.on('keyup', e => {
                    this.update(editor)
                })

                this.$parent.$on('reset', () => editor.setContent(''))
            },

            update(editor) {
                this.content = editor.getContent()
                this.$emit('input', this.content)
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

I'm using wrapper-component like 10 times in my document.

The data in child-component is the same for every wrapper-component, the state is shared/overwritten by the data in the last instantiated child-component. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean by *'the state is shared/overwritten'*. Could you be more explicit about precisely which bits seem to be shared and what observations lead you to that conclusion? The first thing that jumps out at me from the code is the bit starting `this.tinyOptions = Object.assign`. That'll be sharing the same `tinyOptions` object between all instances. They'll all be the object `window.tinyMCESettings`, albeit that object keeps being updated by the calls to `Object.assign`.

Comment: `this.tinyOptions` should be local to each component, no? Considering it's in the `data`-property? In tinyOptions there is a property named "selector" which is used by tinymce.init in order to figure out which component it is that should be a tiny editor. Earlier I did that Object.assigning directly on the data-property, but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from the question whether this is **the** problem that you're facing but it is **a** problem.

When you first create `tinyOptions` in the `data` function you are assigning it a new empty object. That is fine. Every instance of your component will have its own, distinct object for that property. Nothing being shared.

However, then we hit this:

```js
this.tinyOptions = Object.assign(window.tinyMCESettings, {
    selector: '#' + this.id,
    init_instance_callback: this.initInstanceCallback,
}, this.init)
```

This assigns a different object to the `tinyOptions` property, so the original empty object is thrown away. That, by itself, would not be a problem. But let's consider what's going on here. The code above is roughly equivalent to the following:

```js
window.tinyMCESettings.selector = '#' + this.id
window.tinyMCESettings.init_instance_callback = this.initInstanceCallback,

for (const prop in this.init) {
    window.tinyMCESettings[prop] = this.init[prop]
}

this.tinyOptions = window.tinyMCESettings
```

So what it's doing is updating the properties of the object `window.tinyMCESettings`, then assigning that object to the `tinyOptions` property.

All of your components will be grabbing that same `window.tinyMCESettings` object and changing its properties. While each component has its own distinct `tinyOptions` property, all of those properties will end up pointing at the same object.

One solution would be to copy everything to a new, empty object:

```js
this.tinyOptions = Object.assign({}, window.tinyMCESettings, {
    selector: '#' + this.id,
    init_instance_callback: this.initInstanceCallback,
}, this.init)
```

Personally I would use `...` syntax instead:

```js
this.tinyOptions = {
    ...window.tinyMCESettings,
    selector: '#' + this.id,
    init_instance_callback: this.initInstanceCallback,
    ...this.init
}
```

The choice is yours.

The key thing to note is that the properties of `window.tinyMCESettings` are now being copied to a new object rather than just using that object directly.

Comment: You're completely correct, I inspected window.tinyMCESettings and selector was indeed the value of the last component added. However, this introduced me to a new issue, the textarea element is just hidden now...